Intentional Overflow
I'm wondering if it is allowed in C++ to use overflow on purpose.
In specific I want to increase a counter every cycle and when uint32_max is reached start from 0.
In my mind the easy way would be:
uint32_t counter = 0;
while(condition)
{
    counter++;
    ...
}

or would you manually reset the counter?:
uint32_t counter = 0;
while(condition)
{
    if(counter == uint32_max)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
    ...
}


Yes it's OK. Such "overflow" of unsigned integral values is well defined and behaves like you expect - i.e. wraps to 0 (this is not true for signed values though).

For standard unsigned integral types, it is fine to use overflow "on purpose", since the behaviour on overflow is well-defined by the C++ standard.    For other types (e.g. signed integral types, floating point types) that is not true.

"on purpose" --What C++ allows and what it does not allow does not depend on the intent of the programmer. Better would be to ask if you can use overflow to reset a counter (i.e. if your desired behavior is guaranteed by the standard).

That is fine because you used uint32_t. Unsigned integers do not overflow but wrap-around from the maximum value to zero. Such behavior is well-defined in C++, unlike signed integer overflow/underflow.
